# How to calculate a specific distance along a multilinestring from a specific point in QGIS

Tags: qgis, distance, road

[image]

I have a shapefile of a road network and another one with some points. What I should achieve is calculating a fixed distance (e.g., 10 km) in all directions along the road network, starting from the given points.

Is there a relatively simple way to do this? All I found requires the use of Python, but I am new to this and having some troubles with it. I am working with QGIS 3.34.

Comment: Have you even googled "QGIS network analysis"?

Comment: "Service area", a network tool, is the magic algorithm you have to look for. See e.g. here https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/403206/88814